# How I can count the total of numbers with python if statement?

Tags: python, list

I want to count the total occurrence of the number `5` in my dataframe `df` with 4 lists inside it (there are 3 numbers `5` in my `df`). But in my code bellow the `if` statement stops when it encounters the first `False` return and does not count the third `5` in the last list in `df`. How I can resolve this?

```
df = [[1,3,5,7,9],[1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10],[2,5,6,8,10]]
n,m,counter=0,5,0

for i in range(4):
    if df[n].count(m):
        print('ok')
        counter=counter+1
        n=n+1
    else:
        print('NO')
print(counter)
```

Comment: you're not iterating properly. instead of using `for i in range(4)` use something like this:

Comment: `for l in df:
 for item in l:
  if item==5:
   print('ok')
   counter += 1
  else:
   print('NO')
print counter`

Comment: Your `df` is not a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks n1c9!! "Learning, and perhaps even helping others!" I understandig, I had to do two iterations. My final code is:  for l in df: 
 for item in l: 
  if item == m: 
   counter +=  1 
print counter

Answer (score 3):

You need to index with `i` not with `n` here:

```
if df[n].count(m):
```

Better:

```
if df[i].count(m):
```

Shorter way:

```
sum(x.count(5) for x in df)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Müller! Your shorter way is a very good solution!

Answer (score 1):

I approached the problem a bit differently, but here is the code I would use to solve this problem:

```
df = [[1,3,5,7,9],[1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10],[2,5,6,8,10]]

m=5
counter = 0
for sublist in df:
    counter += sublist.count(m)
print(counter)
```

Rather than creating multiple variables and having a 'for loop', I set up a for loop to iterate through each list in the original list.

Comment: Thanks Apero! Your approach is another interesting way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting to look at every list because you are only incrementing `n` if you do find a '5' in the list. But you only try 4 times, so you are effectively looking at `[2,4,6,8,10]` twice and then running out of `range`.

Comment: Thanks Sam! You are right, I understood my mistake.